# Only first page prints correctly when using CSS break-before: always

Tags: html, css, page-break

I have created a dynamic web page for packing slips and it forces a page break before all packing slips except the first one. All packing slips are formatted correctly when they print. However only the first packing slip is centered horizontally on the page and all others are pulled to the right and therefore cut off. While the amount that is being cut off is minute it is still annoying. Is there a way to force each page to center horizontally on the page like the first one?

Comment: we would need to see your html and css

Comment: otherwise margin auto on the div or text-align center on the parent might do it

Comment: Are you sure this has to do do with page-break-before, or does it also happen without?